# XSLT select multiple items from results

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi im trying to select values from multiple results and populate it to different cells.

I have the following XML data.

```
    <objects name="Completed on time">
    <object>
        <description type="string">Affiliate RA</description>
        <cnt type="double">31</cnt>
    </object>
    <object>
        <description type="string">Records &amp; Information Management</description>
        <cnt type="double">431</cnt>
    </object>
    <object>
        <description type="string">Regulatory Affairs, MedDoc &amp; R&amp;D Quality</description>
        <cnt type="double">92</cnt>
    </object>
    <object>
        <description type="string">Regulatory Business Operations</description>
        <cnt type="double">490</cnt>
    </object>
    <object>
        <description type="string">Regulatory Data &amp; Submission Management</description>
        <cnt type="double">607</cnt>
    </object>
</objects>
<objects name="Not completed on time">
    <object>
        <descriptionoverdue type="string">Affiliate RA</descriptionoverdue>
        <cntoverdue type="double">6</cntoverdue>
    </object>
    <object>
        <descriptionoverdue type="string">Records &amp; Information Management</descriptionoverdue>
        <cntoverdue type="double">148</cntoverdue>
    </object>
    <object>
        <descriptionoverdue type="string">Regulatory Affairs, MedDoc &amp; R&amp;D Quality</descriptionoverdue>
        <cntoverdue type="double">83</cntoverdue>
    </object>
    <object>
        <descriptionoverdue type="string">Regulatory Business Operations</descriptionoverdue>
        <cntoverdue type="double">180</cntoverdue>
    </object>
    <object>
        <descriptionoverdue type="string">Regulatory Data &amp; Submission Management</descriptionoverdue>
        <cntoverdue type="double">320</cntoverdue>
    </object>
</objects>
<objects name="Not completed overdue">
    <object>
        <descriptionpending type="string">Records &amp; Information Management</descriptionpending>
        <cntpending type="double">27</cntpending>
    </object>
    <object>
        <descriptionpending type="string">Regulatory Affairs, MedDoc &amp; R&amp;D Quality</descriptionpending>
        <cntpending type="double">1</cntpending>
    </object>
    <object>
        <descriptionpending type="string">Regulatory Business Operations</descriptionpending>
        <cntpending type="double">25</cntpending>
    </object>
    <object>
        <descriptionpending type="string">Regulatory Data &amp; Submission Management</descriptionpending>
        <cntpending type="double">30</cntpending>
    </object>
</objects>
```

And I have made the following xslt 1.0 code to process the data

```
                <xsl:for-each select="/result/objects[@name = 'Completed on time']/object | /result/objects[@name = 'Not completed on time']/object | /result/objects[@name = 'Not completed overdue']/object">
                <Row>
                    <Cell>
                        <Data ss:Type="String">
                            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                        </Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell>
                        <Data ss:Type="Number">
                            <xsl:value-of select="cnt"/>
                        </Data>
                    
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell>
                        <Data ss:Type="Number">
                            <xsl:value-of select="cntoverdue"/>
                        </Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell>
                        <Data ss:Type="Number">
                            <xsl:value-of select="cntpending"/>
                        </Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

[The results look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovNS3.png)

This is the result

```
            <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">Affiliate RA</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">31</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">Records &amp; Information Management</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">431</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">Regulatory Affairs, MedDoc &amp; R&amp;D Quality</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">92</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">Regulatory Business Operations</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">490</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">Regulatory Data &amp; Submission Management</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">607</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">6</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">148</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">83</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">180</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">320</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">27</Data>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">25</Data>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">30</Data>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
```

[And I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG7Zz.png)

Desired result:

```
            <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">Affiliate RA</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">31</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">6</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Height="30.052173913043475">
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">Records &amp; Information Management</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">431</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">148</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">27</Data>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Height="30.052173913043475">
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">Regulatory Affairs, MedDoc &amp; R&amp;D Quality</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">92</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">83</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Height="30.052173913043475">
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">Regulatory Business Operations</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">490</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">180</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">25</Data>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row ss:Height="30.052173913043475">
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">Regulatory Data &amp; Submission Management</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">607</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">320</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">30</Data>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
```

I can't figure out why it populates with zeros instead of the right data. And right data is added below where it should be.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Consider to post both the wanted result as well as the one you get as formatted and readable code samples in your question, not as pictures. And explain the logic behind the wanted result, it is not clear why you process different elements but seem to want to expect or seem to want to merge data, perhaps you want to group `object` by `description`? Also tell us which XSLT version and/or processor you use.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Thank for the input. I have edited and added the processed result end desired result.

Comment: It seems like a grouping problem to group the `object` by `description`. Look into Muenchian grouping http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html